# Unable to SSH after enforcing SELinux?

Tags: ssh, selinux

I have modified ”SELINUX=enforcing“ in /etc/selinux/config.But after restarting the machine,I can't ssh to my machine.
Prompt that
/bin/bash: Permission denied

Comment: You did not ask a question. And also there is a chance https://serverfault.com/ would be a better fit

Comment: I don't know. Why didn't you ask a question?

Comment: I don't how to use stackoverflow.Is this not a question?I think I asked a question.What do you want me to do?

Comment: Reinstall linux then, that is a solution.

Comment: But the data will lose.

Comment: Restore it from backups.

Comment: ```setsebool -P ssh_sysadm_login on``` or something to that effect

Answer (score 2):

When you edited the SELINUX for the first time or when switching between different types of policy, you need to relabel the filesystem. The below steps will do the relabel process automatically as shown in the procedures:

1. Restart server

```
    reboot
```

2. On the GRUB display, press “e” to start editing the selected menu item.
3. Perform a break at an early stage of the boot process by typing 「rd.break」 at the end of the line starting
   with kernel=.

```
    kernel=... UTF-8 rd.break
```

4. Once ready press CTRL+X to start the boot process.
5. Check write access on the /sysroot mount point. By default this mount point is mounted only with the read-only (ro) access

```
    mount | grep sysroot
    =/dev/mapper/rhel-root on /sysroot type xfs (ro,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
```

6. Remount the sysroot directory with read & write access.

```
    mount -o remount,rw /sysroot
    mount | grep sysroot
    =/dev/mapper/rhel-root on /sysroot type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
```

7. Enter chroot system

```
    chroot /sysroot
    (new prompt) sh-4.4#
```

8. Force file-system relabeling. Next time when you will reboot the system, it will relabel the filesystem for
   SElinux automatically.This usually occurs when labeling a file system for SELinux for the first time, or when
   switching between different types of policy, such as changing from the targeted to the strict policy.

```
    touch /.autorelabel
```

9. Exit the chroot. Reboot the machine

```
    exit
    logout or reboot (it will take time)
```

10. Now you should be able to login with ssh.